# Is it possible to use Git to do complex long-running migrations, keeping parallel sources intact?

Tags: git, version-control, migration, integration

I'm attempting to do something rather difficult, and it seems to me git should be able to help.  My team is migrating onto a new engineering system, and the new system uses git.  Migrating to the new system requires some moves/renames/edits on a reasonable portion of the files we are using as the build system is a bit different. The old engineering system however has dozens of commits a day.

It seems to me that I should be able to set up an "integration" branch in git that represents the state of the old source tree, and then do something in another branch that represents all the changes being made to the old sources, resolving merge conflicts as they happen, but keeping the "move/rename" operations.

I'm assuming rebase should be able to help with this, but I'm not sure I know git well enough to really internalize best practices on this one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to do, but it sounds like [`rerere`](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) might be useful.

Comment: @Chris: `git rerere` stores only resolution of textual conflicts (this should help with 'edit' part); OTOH git does rename detection so moves/renames should be not a problem.

Comment: Any good documentation on how git DOES the move/renames?